# Powershell: two options: replace special characters of file names

Tags: powershell, replace, rename

I don't know Powershell and tend to do most of my fiddling in CMD.
I've come across two methods of what I think does the same thing in Powershell (replace an illegal with legal character compatible w/ Windows File Explorer)?
I'm wondering if one of the below is recommended over the other? Is either of them really NOT recommended at all?

`Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\]", ")"}`

`Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace("\]", ")"}`

Also wondering why the below two are the way they are. Seems like one would error out.

`$_.name -replace`

`$_.Name.replace`

Thanks for any information.

Comment: `]` isn't an illegal character tho. Both methods are Ok to use but `.Replace` is literal, so in your example it will only replace a literal `\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are Ok to use but the difference is that [`.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) is literal replacement, in your example, it will try to find and replace a literal `\]`, whereas [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-operator) uses regular expressions and, if you want to match a literal `]` then you need to escape that character with `\`. See [Escaping characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3#escaping-characters).

In both examples I would definitely recommend to perform a pre filtering to find only files containing a `]`. If you want both to do exactly the same (replace `]` for a `)` from files) then:

```bash
# With -replace:
Get-ChildItem -Filter *]* -File -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\]', ')' }

# With .Replace:
Get-ChildItem -Filter *]* -File -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace(']', ')') }
```